# When does the writer of a named pipe do its work?

Tags: linux, named-pipes

I'm trying to understand how a named pipe behaves in terms of performance. Say I have a large file I am decompressing that I want to write to a named pipe (/tmp/data):

```
gzip --stdout -d data.gz > /tmp/data
```

and then I sometime later run a program that reads from the pipe:

```
wc -l /tmp/data
```

When does gzip actually decompress the data, when I run the first command, or when I run the second and the reader attaches to the pipe? If the former, is the data stored on disk or in memory?

Comment: shouldn't that be gunzip to decompress ?

Comment: think its valid. From the man page:` "-d, --decompress, --uncompress. This option selects decompression rather than compression."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes (named or otherwise) have only a very small buffer if any -- so if nothing is reading, then nothing (or very little) can be written.

In your example, `gzip` will do very little until `wc` is run, because before that point its efforts to write output will block. Out-of-the-box there is no nontrivial buffer either on-disk or in-memory, though tools exist which will implement such a buffer for you, should you want one -- see [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) with its `-B` argument, or the no-longer-maintained (and, sadly, [removed from Debian by folks who didn't understand its function](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-qa@lists.debian.org/msg13635.html)) *bfr*.